# idx workbench migration error - utilitybar

Tags: flexipages

In field: utilityBar - no FlexiPage named Industries_CPQ_UtilityBar found

i get this error while trying to migrate. whhat could cause it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your app has a utility bar.  Salesforce add this automatically for you.

You need to include the utility bar flexipage in your deployment.